# Is a user requirement document commonly used? Is there an alternate name or more common type of document that already exists?

Tags: design, documentation, requirements, planning

It is common for business analysts to create business requirement documents to detail the business process and rules that underpin how the system needs to behave. It is also common for solution architects to create technical requirement documents to detail the technology solution that define the way different technology layers, systems and components interact to deliver the working system.

With the prevalence of UX design processes and methods, why is it not common or necessary for UX designers to create user requirement documents to detail the high level user mental model and behaviours that define the interaction and behaviour that the system needs to have with the users to provide the optimal user experience? Are there other types of documentation or names that are used for this type of information presented and used in project design/planning?

To clarify the question, the document should be used to communicate with people within both the business and technology sections of the organisation, and also allows it to be translated into more detailed UX design requirements that form the basis of in-depth research, design and testing activities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User Experience desigenrs work with a number deliverables but a lot of these are flexible to adapt to the variety of business goals and work methodologies. Adding to that, the UX field is shifting heavily towards business strategy, which in time will generate new types of deliverables and frameworks.

That being said, there is a number of approaches used to streamline processes, gain efficiency and go about delivering UX, most of which are quite familiar like wireframes, sitemaps etc but some are not. Peter Morville coauthor of [Information Architecture for the World Wide Web](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596527341.do) outlined some of these deliverables in what he called the [User Experience Treasure Map (PDF)](http://semanticstudios.com/pdfs/uxtreasuremap.pdf) A screenshot below:

[image]

One of the deliverables here that is remarkable by its absence is [interaction design patterns](https://www.interaction-design.org/encyclopedia/interaction_design_patterns.html)

**To answer your question directly**: The most useful deliverable in this regard are  **pattern libraries** that allows developers to reference UX requirements easily and reduces the need to design from scratch for problems encountered in the past. what is also used frequently are **interactive prototypes** that help both in testing solutions as well as acting as reference point for developers and designers.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

There is a document that is normally being used as the reference for UX definitions of a project, someone call it interaction design document, and I know that in some firms they are calling that UX document. This document normally consists a summary of discovery action about users needs, results of design research and for example outputs of card sorting or usability study activities. This also includes personas, scenarios, wireframe, storyboard, site-map, and even the details of interaction design considerations for each click or changes in a page/action. If you look up for examples of these interaction design documents in UX projects, you can find some handy version of those as case studies, one of the good one is Booku case study.

Answer (score 0):

Think since UX is still relatively new compared to other disciplines, there's still no standard or common practices to my knowledge. In reality mostly what i see is the processes depend on the nature of the company if its focusing on their own product or have an agency or consultancy structure. One thing is at least with product teams that use agile, these are usually specified in tickets or wiki pages with links to related resources like wireframes, user flow charts, etc.